# Algorithm for finding substrings in a string, that is very fast for the case that the subtrings don't exist?

Tags: c#, algorithm, search, substring

I'm looking for an algorithm for finding all strings in a set of substrings that are contained within a string.

There are a lot of algorithms for this obviously, but in my case most of the time I expect none of the substrings to be found within the string.

So I need an algorithm that is very fast in the case that none of the substrings are contained, even at the cost of the case where they are (since there is additional code at that point anyway).

If it helps, the size of the full strings are usually between 500 bytes - 2 kilboytes, and the size of the substrings are a few bytes ( examples: "%sub", "hh'", "Tracing"), and there could be 5-20 of them.

I'm writing in C# so I'd prefer an answer in that, but even just an abstract algorithm will do.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [Aho–Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm). It is intended for the case of muliple patterns and has linear complexity (plus number of matches, low in your case).

Comment: We did an implementation that creates a mask for the first and last letters and checks them first, and that really beats aho-corasick. So I'm looking for something more specialized along those lines.

Comment: Your patterns have equal length?

Comment: No, but it's still faster.

Comment: Perhaps you need micro-optimization like using SIMD operations.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform multiple search of a few short strings, I guess that a trie is ideal for you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

As a secondary optimization, in case of a failure the trie could tell you how many characters you can skip to continue the search. (But I have no idea how to build the skip table.)